# PowerShell limit entries in text boxes to integer values only

Tags: powershell, textbox, integer, type-conversion

A small program with Windows Forms in PowerShell shall contain a calculator.

I decided to use TextBoxes as input method, however I can't convert the content of these textboxes to integers.

How would I limit the entry in textboxes to integer-only or is there any other way to get user inputs except textboxes that would fit my needs?

Comment: Hello, my question is different from that which is is flagged as my duplicate. I do not try to remove special characters. I try to remove all except numbers. The solution posted over there unfortunately does not work for me. Still any way to get it back? Or is this question now doomed?

Comment: Did you actually *try* the accepted answer to the other question?

Comment: Oh yes I did, I tried to combine multiple solutions from different forums as well as that solution alone. However, it did not changed anything for my problem but if you are sure that is works with it I'll better double check

Comment: The dupe target does exactly what you ask for - prevents any character, except for numerical digits

Comment: Depending on your powershell version you may have to change the variable scope inside the scriptblock

Comment: perfect! I changed the scope of the variable to global, it works now! Thanks a lot!